# Link for social button share on Telegram

Tags: telegram

Good evening,

In a classic post page of WordPress, I've four share buttons. In don't found the right link to share the post on Telegram. This one runs good for Facebook:

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=&t=" class="social-share-button social-share-button-fb" title="Partager sur Facebook" target="_blank" rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer" aria-label="Partager sur Facebook" onclick="window.open('https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=' + encodeURIComponent(document.URL) + '&t=' + encodeURIComponent(document.URL)); return false;"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 320 512"><!--! Font Awesome Pro 6.2.0 by @fontawesome - https://fontawesome.com License - https://fontawesome.com/license (Commercial License) Copyright 2022 Fonticons, Inc. --><path d="M279.14 288l14.22-92.66h-88.91v-60.13c0-25.35 12.42-50.06 52.24-50.06h40.42V6.26S260.43 0 225.36 0c-73.22 0-121.08 44.38-121.08 124.72v70.62H22.89V288h81.39v224h100.17V288z"/></svg>
```

Any idea for the same to Telegram? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
https://t.me/share/url?url={url}&text={text}
```

where `{url}` is the URL the user will be sharing and `{text}` is an optional description that will be included with the link. Both values should be URL-encoded.

PHP Example:

```
function telegramForwardButton($url, $text = '') {
  $share_url = 'https://t.me/share/url?url='.rawurlencode($url).'&text='.rawurlencode($text);
  return "<a href=\"{$share_url}\">Share</a>";
}
```

[SOURCE](https://core.telegram.org/widgets/share#custom-buttons)

Comment: Thank you ; I had seen this article on the Telegram blog, but the link don't run or perhaps I don't use the good code in place of {url} and {text}…

Comment: What language are you writing in

Comment: html in a code block of Oxygen builder.